# multidimensional search of pattern within specific key and return all requested arrays php

Tags: php, arrays, search, multidimensional-array, return

Hi  I'm struggling to do a code that retrieves arrays with a certain pattern in certain values within a multidimensional.

```
Array([0]=>
      array(5){
        ['id'] => 'YES1'
        ['name'] => 'what'
        ['val1'] => 'hfka'
        ['val2'] => 'adflj'
        ['val3'] => 'afasf'
     }
      [1]=>
     array(5){
        ['id'] => 'KAT1'
        ['name'] => 'what'
        ['val1'] => 'hfka'
        ['val2'] => 'YES1,NO3'
        ['val3'] => 'afasf'
        }
      [2]=>
       array(5){
        ['id'] => 'BAS2'
        ['name'] => 'sdf'
        ['val1'] => 'hfka'
        ['val2'] => 'BOO2,dfslj'
        ['val3'] => 'jal'
     }
      [3]=>
    array(5){
        ['id'] => 'YES4'
        ['name'] => 'sdf'
        ['val1'] => 'hfka'
        ['val2'] => 'BOO2,dfslj'
        ['val3'] => 'jal'
       }
```

.. and so forth.

After triggering the right php code:

Intended result:

```
Result Array([0]=>
          array(5){
               'id' => 'YES4'
               'name' => 'sdf'
               'val1' => 'hfka'
               'val2' => 'BOO2,dfslj'
               'val3' => 'jal'
           }
             [1]=>
           array(5){
               'id' => 'YES1'
               'name' => 'what'
               'val1' => 'hfka'
               'val2' => 'adflj'
               'val3' => 'afasf'
             }
```

so for each array, I would like to search for the pattern 'YES' in the key 'id' and return all  arrays with all the information.  I've tried the foreach(x2) with preg_match and a few other ones but they don't produce the result I'd like to receive..ie the result is true; an empty array; or includes other arrays because the experimental code was too general and the pattern was located in another key.

eventually, I have in mind to end up with a function getArraysOfSpecificTypeofID($pattern,$array).

**UPDATE**

fixed up the array code to reflect what is returned when the array is vardumped.

I forgot to mention that the data in the array was retrieved from a mysql query.  I'm not sure if this changes anything, but I don't think it should because the var_dump($theoriginalarray) returns similar information as an array that was manually typed up in php.  I

I have tried the following codes that have been suggested by helpers plus foreach (array as value), if (preg_match('YES', value) and return $results which seems to returns an empty array.

this works but gives me all the arrays that contains 'YES'

```
$pattern= "/YES/";
```

$matches = array_filter($array, function($value) use($pattern) {
return preg_grep($pattern, $value); });

this also works but gives me the values I don't want:

```
foreach ($array as $key) {
  if (!preg_match('*CAT*', $key){
  $results = $key;
  }
}
```

weirdly, if I remove '!' or even add ==true to the end of preg_match- I receive a null value.  Exactly the same situation when I use strpos rather than prey_match.

...help, this is befuddling me.

**UPDATE 2**
Thank you for all your help.
I needed to parse my array into another variable before attempting to to filter it.  Thanks Mark, your code worked perfectly for what I was trying to attempt.

Comment: Most people will want you to post your attempt(s).

Comment: `$resultArray = array_filter($originalArray, function($value) { return fnmatch('*YES*', $value['id']); } );`

Comment: hi Mark, the code, unfortunately, returns an empty array.  It returns values when you remove the ['id'] but it returns all the arrays that contains 'YES,' including the the arrays that have 'YES' in key val2

Comment: The code I provided shouldn't return an empty array, nor does it when I run a test - [demo](http://ideone.com/Tw8MOz)

Answer (score 0):

You may be missing the "array(" after the key value.

```
array(
0=>array('id'=>'YES1','name'=>'what','val1'=>'hfka','val2'=>'adflj','val3'=>'afasf'),
1=>array('id'=>'KAT1','name'=>'what','val1'=>'hfka','val2'=>'YES1,NO3','val3'=>'afasf'),
2=>array('id'=>'BAS2','name'=>'sdf','val1'=>'hfka','val2'=>'BOO2,dfslj','val3'=>'jal'),
3=>array('id'=>'YES4','name'=>'sdf','val1'=>'hfka','val2'=>'BOO2,dfslj','val3'=>'jal')
);
```

**When I tested your array did not work and this one did.**

Comment: hi I really appreciate your input.  I don't think its the array( because the  array I'm trying to query has been created and set by a previous mysql query.

Answer (score 0):

**Now Tested**

```
<?php
header('Content-Type: text/plain; charset=utf-8');

$array=array(
0=>array('id'=>'YES1','name'=>'what','val1'=>'hfka','val2'=>'adflj','val3'=>'afasf'),
1=>array('id'=>'KAT1','name'=>'what','val1'=>'hfka','val2'=>'YES1,NO3','val3'=>'afasf'),
2=>array('id'=>'BAS2','name'=>'sdf','val1'=>'hfka','val2'=>'BOO2,dfslj','val3'=>'jal'),
3=>array('id'=>'YES4','name'=>'sdf','val1'=>'hfka','val2'=>'BOO2,dfslj','val3'=>'jal')
);


foreach($array as $val){
  if (strpos($val['id'],'YES')!==false){
    $result[] = $val;
  } 
}
print_r($result);
```

**The Result**

```
[0] => Array
    (
        [id] => YES1
        [name] => what
        [val1] => hfka
        [val2] => adflj
        [val3] => afasf
    )

[1] => Array
    (
        [id] => YES4
        [name] => sdf
        [val1] => hfka
        [val2] => BOO2,dfslj
        [val3] => jal
    )
```

Comment: strpos is much faster than regex

Comment: hi thanks for your help, but when i var_dump($results), it returns with an empty array.  I tried it with a similar code where the code uses preg_match or preg_grep, instead of strpos, and the $result returns with an empty array.

Comment: I will test and debug, give me a couple of minutes.

Comment: Tested, debugged, and functional.

Comment: The problem was strpos() returned a position of zero (the first character) which was equated to a false.